# Вернулся результат -1.#IO

Tags: c

Некоторые вычисления вернули результат `-1.#IO`. Что это значит?

Comment: Похоже на NaN

Comment: Вроде бы [NaN и есть](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/21/10395734.aspx). У вас MSVC, да? Проверьте функцией `_isnan`.